# Подключения к MySQL

Tags: mysql, golang

Наприсал функцию на go, которая поднимает соединение с бд, вынимает данные и закрывает соединение, но после отработки функции все равно остается соединение, до тех пор пока не приостановлю программу

```
func selectSites() (sites siteList, list string) {

    connectSetting := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True",
        config.AppConfig.DB.User,
        config.AppConfig.DB.Pass,
        config.AppConfig.DB.Host,
        strconv.Itoa(config.AppConfig.DB.Port),
        config.AppConfig.DB.Name,
    )

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", connectSetting)
    defer db.Close()


    rows, err := db.Query(config.AppConfig.SQL.SelectList)
    defer rows.Close()
    if err == nil {
        for rows.Next() {
            err := rows.Scan(&list)
            if err != nil {
                config.InLog("selectSites list parse err %s", err.Error())
                continue
            }
        }

    } else {
        config.InLog("selectSites list err %s", err.Error())
    }

    return
}
```

Количество процессов в бд до запуска программы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Количество процессов в бд после отработки функции
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно сделать, чтоб убить 3й процесс не останавливая программу

Comment: С «MySQL» не работал, но из подозрительного, не обработаны оба `Close()` и `rows.Err()`.

Comment: `kill 1718` убьет по Id процесс

Comment: Ainar-G, что значит не обработаны?

Comment: Какой mysql-драйвер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, в Го принято выносить ошибки в `if`-блоки, тем самым отделяя код обработки ошибок от кода, когда этих ошибок нету. Во-вторых, нет проверки открытия базы данных, в случае ошибки `db.Query()` и `defer db.Close()` вызовут панику. В-третьих, `rows.Err()` не проверяется [database/sql#Rows](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Rows).

Ну и собственно, базы данных используют пул подключений и переиспользуют эти подключения после. В таком случае, создание нового подключения просто возьмёт подключение из пула, вместо того, чтобы создавать новое. Например, если Ваше приложение использует 100 подключений, то, скорее всего, все они будут в пуле - постоянно открытыми, чтобы их можно было использовать после. И Ваше подключение не закрывается драйвером для этих целей.

Обратите внимание на

- [SetConnMaxLifetime](https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.SetConnMaxLifetime)
- [SetMaxIdleConns](https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.SetMaxIdleConns)
- [SetMaxOpenConns](https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.SetMaxOpenConns)

Что соответственно, время жизни подключения, максимум ожидающих подключений и максимум открытых подключений. Все эти настройки относятся к пулу подключений.

```
func selectSites() (sites siteList, list string) {

    connectSetting := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True",
        config.AppConfig.DB.User,
        config.AppConfig.DB.Pass,
        config.AppConfig.DB.Host,
        strconv.Itoa(config.AppConfig.DB.Port),
        config.AppConfig.DB.Name,
    )

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", connectSetting)
    if err != nil {
        config.InLog("opening DB %v", err)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query(config.AppConfig.SQL.SelectList)
    defer rows.Close()
    if err != nil {
        config.InLog("selectSites list err %v", err)
        return
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&list)
        if err != nil {
            config.InLog("selectSites list parse err %v", err)
            return
        }
    }

    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        config.InLog("selectSites list parse err %v", err)
        return
    }

    return
}
```

Ну а остальное зависит уже от того, какой MySQL-драйвер используется. И есть ли ещё в этом приложении подключение к той же БД.